# Is it impossible to get a facebook app approved that tags friends with the posting? I have been told it is

Tags: facebook

I am interested in having a facebook app developed that allows the app user to tag one or many of their friends when it posts. Developers I have spoken with say this will take months to get approved if ever. My app idea requires the ability to post. Looking for a second or third opinion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions posted here surround specific programming problems for developers, not individual company policies.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for tagging are very clear:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process#actioncapabilities-actiontagging
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process#actioncapabilities-mentiontagging

About how long it takes to get `taggable_friends` reviewed:

> The review time estimate will change based on the requested permissions, ranging between 3 to 7 business days.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit#submitforreview

Many people try to use `taggable_friends` for something else, that´s why they don´t get it approved. You are only allowed to use it for tagging, and you need to create a serious and non-spammy App. If you follow the rules, you should get it approved pretty fast.